# pipenv does'nt use pyenv with "pipenv shell" command

Tags: pipenv, pyenv

pyenv is used in "python" command.
But pipenv does'nt use pyenv with "pipenv shell" command when create virtual env.
Why is that happen?

Answer (score 0):

pipenv does not use pyenv python, you have to decide which python you want to use with the --python option:

```
pipenv --python=3.10.6
```

If you already have the virtualenv with the wrong python, you have to remove it first before recreating it:

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv --python=3.10.6
pipenv install
```